# Issue with Chatbot: Messages Not Displaying After Clicking Send Button

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, chatbot

Problem Description:

I am following a YouTube tutorial on how to build a chatbot using Python and JavaScript. The chatbot UI displays correctly, and the button to open the chatbox popup is working fine. However, when I type a message into the input field and click the send button, nothing happens, and the message doesn't show up in the chatbox. I'm wondering why this is the case.

Code:

Here is the code for app.py (used to run the app):

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify

from chat import get_response

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.get("/")
def index_get():
    return render_template("base.html")

@app.post("/predict")
def predict():
   text = request.get_json().get("message")
   # TO-DO: check if text is valid
   response = get_response(text)
   message = {"answer": response}
   return jsonify(message)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=5001)
```

And here is the code for app.js (code for the chatbot itself):

```
class Chatbox {
  constructor() {
    this.args = {
      openButton: document.querySelector(".chatbox__button"),
      sendButton: document.querySelector(".send__button"),
    };

    this.state = false;
    this.messages = [];
  }

  toggleState(chatBox) {
    chatBox.classList.toggle("chatbox--active");
  }

  onSendButton(chatBox) {
    var textField = chatBox.querySelector("input");
    let text1 = textField.value;
    if (text1 === "") {
      return;
    }

    let msg1 = { name: "User", message: text1 };
    this.messages.push(msg1);

    fetch($SCRIPT_ROOT + "/predict", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: text1 }),
      mode: "cors",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((r) => r.json())
      .then((r) => {
        let msg2 = { name: "Sam", message: r.answer };
        this.messages.push(msg2);
        this.updateChatText(chatBox);
        textField.value = "";
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
        this.updateChatText(chatBox);
        textField.value = "";
      });
  }

  updateChatText(chatBox) {
    var html = "";
    this.messages
      .slice()
      .reverse()
      .forEach(function (item, index) {
        if (item.name === "Sam") {
          html +=
            '<div class="messages__item messages__item--visitor">' +
            item.message +
            "</div>";
        } else {
          html +=
            '<div class="messages__item messages__item--operator">' +
            item.message +
            "</div>";
        }
      });

    const chatMessage = chatBox.querySelector(".chatbox__messages");
    chatMessage.innerHTML = html;
  }

  display() {
    const { openButton, sendButton } = this.args;
    const chatBox = document.querySelector(".chatbox__support");

    openButton.addEventListener("click", () => this.toggleState(chatBox));

    sendButton.addEventListener("click", () => this.onSendButton(chatBox));

    const inputNode = chatBox.querySelector("input");
    inputNode.addEventListener("keyup", (event) => {
      if (event.key === "Enter") {
        this.onSendButton(chatBox);
      }
    });
  }
}

const chatbox = new Chatbox();
chatbox.display();
```

Here is the HTML and CSS code for the chatbot in base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Chatbot</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="chatbox">
        <div class="chatbox__support">
            <div class="chatbox__header">
                <div class="chatbox__image--header">
                    <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/circled-user-female-skin-type-5--v1.png" alt="image">
                </div>
                <div class="chatbox__content--header">
                    <h4 class="chatbox__heading--header">Chat support</h4>
                    <p class="chatbox__description--header">Hi. My name is Sam. How can I help you?</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="chatbox__messages">
                <div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="chatbox__footer">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Write a message...">
                <button class="chatbox__send--footer send__button">Send</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="chatbox__button">
            <button><img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/chatbox-icon.svg') }}" /></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    var $SCRIPT_ROOT = "{{ request.script_root|tojson }}";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='app.js') }}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

and here is style.css:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Nunito", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 100%;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

*,
html {
  --primaryGradient: linear-gradient(93.12deg, #581b98 0.52%, #9c1de7 100%);
  --secondaryGradient: linear-gradient(
    268.91deg,
    #581b98 -2.14%,
    #9c1de7 99.69%
  );
  --primaryBoxShadow: 0px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  --secondaryBoxShadow: 0px -10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  --primary: #581b98;
}

/* CHATBOX
=============== */
.chatbox {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 30px;
}

/* CONTENT IS CLOSE */
.chatbox__support {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #eee;
  width: 300px;
  height: 350px;
  z-index: -123456;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

/* CONTENT ISOPEN */
.chatbox--active {
  transform: translateY(-40px);
  z-index: 123456;
  opacity: 1;
}

/* BUTTON */
.chatbox__button {
  text-align: right;
}

.send__button {
  padding: 6px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* HEADER */
.chatbox__header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: orange;
}

/* MESSAGES */
.chatbox__messages {
  margin-top: auto;
  display: flex;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.messages__item {
  background: orange;
  max-width: 60.6%;
  width: fit-content;
}

.messages__item--operator {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.messages__item--visitor {
  margin-right: auto;
}

/* FOOTER */
.chatbox__footer {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
}

.chatbox__support {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  height: 450px;
  width: 350px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}

/* HEADER */
.chatbox__header {
  background: var(--primaryGradient);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: var(--primaryBoxShadow);
}

.chatbox__image--header {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.chatbox__heading--header {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  color: white;
}

.chatbox__description--header {
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  color: white;
}

/* Messages */
.chatbox__messages {
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.messages__item {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  max-width: 70%;
}

.messages__item--visitor,
.messages__item--typing {
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}

.messages__item--operator {
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  background: var(--primary);
  color: white;
}

/* FOOTER */
.chatbox__footer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 20px 20px;
  background: var(--secondaryGradient);
  box-shadow: var(--secondaryBoxShadow);
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.chatbox__footer input {
  width: 80%;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  text-align: left;
}

.chatbox__send--footer {
  color: white;
}

.chatbox__button button,
.chatbox__button button:focus,
.chatbox__button button:visited {
  padding: 10px;
  background: white;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-top-left-radius: 50px;
  border-top-right-radius: 50px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Additional Context:

I have implemented a chatbot based on the tutorial, but when I type a message and click the send button, nothing happens. I have checked the code, and it seems that the onSendButton() function is not being triggered correctly. I expect the message to be sent to the server using the fetch() function and then added to the chatbox messages using the updateChatText() function.

I would appreciate any help in identifying why the messages are not displaying after clicking the send button. Thank you!